# Redirect URL using?

Tags: html, redirect

Is there any way to redirect a URL by having 1 centeral redirect page like:

```
example.com/redirect
```

and having a sort of attribute at the end to redirect to a certain page,

```
example.com/redirect?pagename
```

and in the code it will tell the webpage to redirect to the desired page.
Sorry if I baffled or anything I'm quite new to this sorta stuff.

Comment: Seems kinda pointless.  At the point where you are building a "global redirector", and then then defining key-value pairs for each redirect, and then directing to the redirect page for the redirect, why not just redireect directly to the final destination?

Comment: Not using HTML. You need either server configuration or a programming language to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can by adding in your redirect page or 
**javascript:**

```
<script>
window.location = "http://google.com";
</script>
```

or
**PHP:**

```
<?php
header("Location:http://google.com")
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

That is possible if you can have a CGI script, FastCGI program, or PHP script behind that URL.  It can then look at the parameter and dynamically create a reply page with HTML redirect in the header.

Comment: There are dozens of other methods that a server can trigger a program to determine the response. CGI, FastCGI and mod_php are just three of them.